# Printing all the arguments in javascript function

Tags: javascript

```js
 x([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

function x(a){
  console.log(a);
  }
```

Why is the result `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` and not `([1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3)`?

Comment: You hand over three arguments to the function, but catch one the first on. You log the first one. The first argument contains the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the result [1,2,3,1,2,3] and not ([1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3)

Because you are passing 3 parameters when calling the `x` function:

- Parameter 1: `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` (a javascript arra of integers)
- Parameter 2: `2` (an integer)
- Parameter 3: `3` (an integer)

but your `x` function only takes a single parameter:

```
function x(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
```

So basically what gets printed here is the value of the first parameter you passed to this function.

If you want to take into account other parameters you could do so:

```
function x(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing three arguments to the `x` function, but only accepting one. The array you pass is used as the `a` argument in your function, but there are two numbers passed outside of the array and you are not referencing them at all in your function or log command.

---

You can change your functions signature to accept all 3 arguments:

```
function x(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a, b ,c);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to log **all** of the arguments passed to the function even when you don't know how many will be passed, you can use the `arguments` variable that is available in every function. It contains an array of all the arguments passed to a function:

```
function x() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

var arr = ['a', 'b'];
x(arr, 3, 4); // output: [['a', 'b'], 3 ,4]
```

More info about the usage of the `arguments` variable can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments